# Loop through Ansible variable in in .j2 file

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have one ansible var list defined in group_vars

```
member_list:
        - a
        - b
```

I have one proxy.j2 template

```
{% for var in members_list %} 
server {

server_name {{ var }}-{{ server_name }};
{% endfor %}
```

How could I loop through that list to get the value in .j2 file?

Comment: jinja loops use curly braces, check jinja documentation

Comment: Your iterator is named `var`, so use `var` not `var.members_list`.

Comment: I am getting error var is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using {{ item }} instead of {{ var }}.